# Are there predefined profiles in Darktable to instantly give RAWs some necessary punch?

Tags: darktable, rawtherapee

I am just starting using Darktable 1.4 under Mac OS X 1.4. Before I was using Raw Therapee. What I liked about Raw Therapee are the profiles it ships with, especially as the RAWs that come out of my EOS 20D look very desaturated and boring as they come out of the camera, and the Raw Therapee "Default" profile instantly gives the pictures some punch. It was a good starting point and saves a lot of work. Good profiles are also Punchy and Pop4 BW.

Is there anything similar for Darktable?

Sometimes I like to fiddle on pictures for hours, but sometimes I just what to apply a precanned profile and be done!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There aren't any built in that I'm aware of, but you can just define your own (in Darktable it would be a "style").  I have a base style I start with that adjusts the base curve, increases the saturation slightly, applies profiled denoising (a newer feature which is fantastic), lens correction, etc.

A quick Googling for "Darktable styles" brought up the Darktable Wiki page for sharing styles: http://darktable.org/redmine/projects/darktable/wiki/DarktableStyles

The Darktable User Manual section on styles: http://www.darktable.org/usermanual/ch02s03s08.html.php

And from the Darktable Resources page (http://www.darktable.org/resources/):

> To create a new darktable style just alter your image the way you
>   want. Then click the button located in the history module in darkroom
>   mode to create a style from the current history stack. In advanced
>   options you can include or exclude single modules. To export or import
>   a new style use the styles module in lighttable mode.

Additionally, when you look at the "Base Curve" Module there are a bunch of presets for different manufacturer "biases" (Pentax-Like, Panasonic-like, etc) which will help you get closer to what you want quickly.

Comment: +1 for the last paragraph. That's what the OP is looking for.